# Arrogant and violent

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> You will (3),
> as to dodge my (4),
> you must duck down (5).

What is the 5 letter word?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The missing 5-letter word is likely:

> **BELOW**

As to me, this looks to be a:

> **word ladder** of sorts, where the numbers in brackets represent a missing word which increases in length line by line by the addition of a single letter...

Like so...

> You will BOW,
>  as to dodge my B**L**OW,
>  you must duck down B**E**LOW.

Comment: For anybody wondering "What's the relevance of the title?" I think it's merely to set the tone of the speaker's words.